How to Customize Bibliography Style in LaTeX?
I need help customizing the bibliography style. I've managed to change the citation style, but I also need to adjust the references list style.
Currently, my references look like this:

[27] Rui Tang, Kaishi Taguchi, Hirotomo Nishihara, Takafumi Ishii,
Emilia Morallón, Diego Cazorla-Amorós, Toshihiro Asada, Naoya
Kobayashi, Yasuji Muramatsu, and Takashi Kyotani. Insight into the
origin of carbon corrosion in positive electrodes of supercapacitors.
Journal of materials chemistry A, 7(13):7480–7488, 2019.

I want them to be formatted like this:

[27] R. Tang, K. Taguchi, H. Nishihara, T. Ishii, E. Morallón, D.
Cazorla-Amorós, T. Asada, N. Kobayashi, Y. Muramatsu, and T. Kyotani,
Journal of materials chemistry A, 2019, 7, 7480.

Is this possible? Here is the relevant code for my list of references:
\cleardoublepage

\begin{singlespace}

    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References} 

        {\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}}    
        
    \begin{raggedright}     % because you often get ugly whitespace if justified...
        \bibliography{BibTeX/library}
    \end{raggedright}

\end{singlespace}

Thanks!

With a standard bibtex style, it is almost impossible. There is a reason why the manual for the bibtex styling language is called "Tame the beast". It is much easier to asjust if you use biblatex and the biber programme.

@Scheng The basic answer is, of course, yes: It is possible to modify bibliography styles. The problem I currently see is that from your single example, it is not clear how all the other types of bib entries are to be handled. Moreover, I have my doubts that you really want what you say you want: Do you really plan to cite a journal article without giving the title of the article? Given a list of different types of bib entries and their formatted output, you might want to explain what should be typeset differently.

Update: There is a ''Angewandte Chemie'' bibliography style for natbib, and that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you guys!
\bibliographystyle{angew}

